# Implement const and non-const coeffs() operator for a concatenation of Eigen::Vectors?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am working on a project where I need to combine two Eigen-types and "mimic" them as to behave like one single Eigen type. In particular, there is a requirement for having a class holding two distinct Eigen vectors as member variables, like the one below. 
The catch is, when being passed to an algorithm, this class must behave like a single Eigen-object, which means that I need to mimic some of Eigens API.
Due to memory requirements, it is not a solution to simply copy the two Eigen vectors into a larger Eigen-type and work with that one instead.

For many Eigen matrix methods this combined class is easily realizable, but I am missing a solution for how to realize the const- and non-const getters for the individual coefficients, returned by reference.

In the end, I would like the following to be feasible:

```
class Combined{
public:
 Combined(const Eigen::Vector3d a, const Eigen::Vector3d b): vec1_(a), vec2_(b){}

 const Eigen::Vector6d& coeffs() const {
    // how to implement this?
 }

 Eigen::Vector6d& coeffs() {
    // how to implement this?
 }

 // some other member functions not related to Eigen...
 // ...

private:
  Eigen::Vector3d vec1_;
  Eigen::Vector3d vec2_;
};


int main(){

 Eigen::Vector3d a = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();
 Eigen::Vector3d b = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();

 Combined t (a, b);

 // the const getters should exist:
 Eigen::Vector6d r;
 r= t.coeffs();

 // the non-const getters should allow modification:
 t.coeffs()(0) = 0; // assign some value.


 return 0;
}
```

Any ideas about how to achieve such an implementation would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Except for the constructor, how should `Combined` differ from simply a `Vector6d`?

Comment: In general, the class will do things which go beyond the scope of Eigen::Vector6d, they were simply omitted from the example.

Comment: Without more details, I'd say, just use a `Vector6d` ...

Comment: Providing additional detail will unfortunately not change the nature of the quesiton. We can safely assume that it is not an option simply store them in a Vector6d.

Comment: Especially, since you store `vec1_` and `vec2_` by value, I see absolutely no difference to just storing a `Vector6d` (you can still access the "subvectors" using `head()`, `segment()` and/or `tail()`). It would be a different question, if you wanted changes in `t.coeffs()` reflect to the original `a`, `b` vectors.

Comment: Again - I know that introducing a vector 6d is a trivial solution which would work. But this is not the reason why I post the question. I am specifically interested in how you would do it if you were not allowed to introduce a Vector6d. E.g. how would you implement t.segment(1,3), for the combined class, returning a non-const reference?

Comment: I mean you could implement a function like `Scalar& coeff(Index k) { return k<3 ? vec1_(k) : vec2_(k-3);}` But I still don't see what you intend to do here.

Comment: And if `vec1_` and `vec2_` happen to be stored consecutively (without any padding between them), you could just return a `Map` of the combined size, pointing to the first element of the first vector. But that would be completely inferior to simply storing a `Vector6d` ...

Comment: Thanks for this pointer (`Scalar& coeff(Index k) { return k<3 ? vec1_(k) : vec2_(k-3);}`), its already solving a part of my problem. But now, I would still be interested in how to solve the above mentioned issue of how to mimic the full vector `t.coeffs()` without storing a Vector6d explicitly. How do I store vec1_ and vec2_consecutively?